Space domain and phasor domain super-imposition in case of a 2 pole AC machine
I have been undergoing several doubts about the space-time relationship in an AC rotating machine but recently , I convinced myself that, due to the production of the RMF (rotating magnetic field ) , which is both a space rotating vector as well as a time phasor , the space or mechanical angle (θ_m) and the electrical or phase angle (θ_e) gets related to each other by the formula :
θ_e = (P/2)×(θ_m) where "P" is the no. of poles in the machine .
From here , I myself drew a conclusion that if I consider a 2 pole machine , the space vectors are the same as their corresponding time phasors..provided the quantity should be both a phasor as well as a rotating vector...and such kind of the quantity that exists in rotating AC machines is the RMF . Considering this assumption, I tried plotting the phasors as well as the vectors on the same plane as now we know that an impact in physical rotation in space has equal impact in time . Now , let's take a 2 pole induction machine, having three phase balanced currents flowing through coils in stator slots with their axes mutually 120 degrees apart from one another produces a RMF rotating at synchronous speed in a given positive phase sequence (Let's consider it to be anticlockwise rotation.) and the rotor is also rotating in the same direction with speed less than synchronous speed.
Now at an instant , when the mutual rotating magnetic field flux of stator linking with the rotor conductors is aligned along the horizontal axis of the machine from left to right in space. Then , my question is that , if we consider the flux as the mutual flux phasor , then the maximum emf phasor should be 90 degrees lagging with respect to the flux phasor , which in space would mean that the slots lying along the vertical axis of the machine should have the maximum induced emf but if we go by the formula E = ( v x B )•dl,
then , it stands out to be contradicting to what I supposed using the previous interpretation,  as the conductors lying in the axis normal to the flux phasor , would have velocity either in direction of the flux or in opposite direction of the flux resulting in a zero cross product value of (v × B) ( as sin(0 degrees) = sin (180 degrees) = 0 )...which implies that no emf would be induced in those conductors at all..that's the main contradiction I am facing . Please let me know if my understanding is correct and it would be a great pleasure if you all help me sort out the flaws that I am having in my interpretations to solve my confusion.

The sum of all 3 phases will be 0 due to the phase shift of 120°.  If A is max (0°), then B is at 120° and C is at -120°.
